# How to clear all inputs after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear all inputs value whenever result succeed.

I have tried unbind from Jquery but doesn't get any result

so any suggestion would be great

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Result"></div>
        <form id="Form" action="File.php" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" name="Name" />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="Pass" />
            <br/>
            <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Run Code" />
        </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#Submit").click(function()
                {
                    $("#Form").submit(function(e)
                    {
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: $(this).attr("action"),
                            type: "POST",
                            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
                            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                            {
                                $("#Result").html(data);
                            }
                        });

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });

                    $("#Form").submit();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

please feel free to ask for more details

Comment: You should really stop uppercasing the first letter of everything you write, and a good advice is to never use the name or id `submit` for any element inside a form.

Comment: As for clearing all the inputs, `$('input').val('')` !

Comment: Another good advice would be to not bind event handlers inside event handlers, as you're adding a new event handler for the form submit event every time you click the button.

Comment: @adeneo, i really like to uppercasing the first letter of everything, and about your advice i didnt get your means ...

Comment: In the old days of XHTML attributes used be case-sensitive, and it was good practice to write all lowercase, today HTML5 is in most ways case-insensitive, but classes etc. are still case-sensitive, and it's still good practice to write all lowercase, it's not really a "I like" kinda thing. Look around at other code, have you ever seen anyone else capitalizing everything in the HTML they write, or is it just you. If it's just you, do you think these other more experienced people are right, or you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear all inputs using

```
$("input[type='text']").val('');
```

---

You are binding an event handler inside another event handler. Each time the button is clicked, a new handler is attached to the form. So, after `n` number of clicks, you'll be sending `n` number of `ajax` requests, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qjsngsf8/)

Ideally, your code should be

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   $("#Submit").click(function () {
     $("#Form").submit();
   });

   $("#Form").submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         url: $(this).attr("action"),
         type: "POST",
         data: $(this).serializeArray(),
         success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             $("input[type='text']").val(''); // reset the input values
             $("#Result").html(data);
         }
     });
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qjsngsf8/3/).

*Side note:* You can simply use a `submit` button instead of triggering the form submission manually like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qjsngsf8/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
$(document).find('input').each(function(){
   $(this).val('');
});
```

More info on: http://api.jquery.com/val/